# Python will not print to a text file

Tags: python

For some reason, the following code is unable to print to `Cache.txt`

```
import random
import time

text_file = open("Cache.txt", "w")
text_file.write("Numbers Used \n")

print("Welcome to the Bingo number generator")
UserNumber = str((random.randint(1,90)))
print(UserNumber)
text_file.write ("UserNumber")
text_file.close
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with this code?

Comment: What do you mean "will not print"? Are you saying that after running the code, the file does _not_ contain "Numbers Used" and "UerNumber"? Or are you asking about the `print` statement? Have you read the documentation on the `print` statement to see how you can tell it where to write?

Answer (score 6):

you need to call `close()` function like this:

```
text_file.close()
```

Plus, a more pythonic way would be to call `open()` with context manager [with](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) :

```
with open("Cache.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write("Numbers Used \n")
    print("Welcome to the Bingo number generator")
    UserNumber = str((random.randint(1,90)))
    print(UserNumber)
    text_file.write ("UserNumber")
```

No need to call `close()` doing that way